# GWT Event Bus concept in other framework

Tags: gwt, frameworks, event-handling, event-bus

I am not aware of the many frameworks on the market but i wanted to know something, Like the event bus concept in GWT, does this technique exist in other framework??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many UI frameworks use an EventBus model. Events are just asynchronous messages. UI frameworks usually use these asynchronous mechanisms for notifications because they don't want to block the user from interacting with the system while it is processing the last change they made to the UI. Sometimes people write these busses themselves using the Observer Pattern, and sometimes the frameworks provide them.

Events and event buses have parallels in other asynchronous systems. For example, message oriented middleware (e.g. a JMS server) is a cross-process or cross-system mechanism that is conceptually the same thing as a EventBus.

Answer (score 1):

[EventBus](http://www.eventbus.org/) - This API seems to implement what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think Event Bus is to decouple the sender and receiver, you may take a look for Listener Pattern in Design Pattern.